# WKWebView: Get title of selected link

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

What is the easiest way to get the title of a link selected on a website loaded into a `WKWebView`?

Example: When a user taps the link

```
<a href="http://www.foo.com">Go to foo</a>
```

I want to get the contents of the `<a>` element (`Go to foo` in this case).

It's straightforward to get the link URL through `WKNavigationDelegate` but I couldn't find anything that exposes the title directly. I managed to get the title by injecting Javascript into the web view but this feels a little clumsy (see below).

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds)
        view.addSubview(webView)
        webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://stackoverflow.com")!))
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
    }

    func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        print("Link URL: \(navigationAction.request.URL)")

        let script = "function findLink() {" +
                       "var els = document.getElementsByTagName('a');" +
                       "for (var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) {" +
                         "var el = els[i];" +
                         "if (el.href === '\(navigationAction.request.URL!.absoluteString)') {" +
                           "return el.innerHTML;" +
                         "}" +
                       "}" +
                       "return null;" +
                     "}" +
                     "findLink();";
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(script) { (result, error) -> Void in
            if let result = result {
                print("Link Title: \(result)")
            }
        }

        decisionHandler(.Allow)
    }

}
```

Is there any better way to do this?